# Webform: Hide the "add more" button

Tags: 8, webforms

I would like to get rid of the ajax "add more items" button at the bottom of a multiple elements form item.

The D8 webform I'm building has a custom composite element with multiple values allowed. The table form display has nice + and – buttons in each row. The "Add x more items" element below the table is not needed.

In the advanced tab, under "Multiple settings", there is only an option to hide the +/– buttons, not the "Add x more items" element.

**Additional information:**

Webform module version: 8.x-5.0-rc7
YAML Source (excerpt):

```
   fieldset_teilnehmer:
    '#type': fieldset
    '#title': Teilnehmer
    teilnehmer:
      '#type': custom_composite
      '#title': Teilnehmer
      '#required': true
      '#required_error': 'Bitte tragen Sie die Teilnehmer ein.'
      '#multiple__label': Teilnehmer
      '#multiple__labels': Teilnehmer
      '#multiple__min_items': '5'
      '#multiple__empty_items': '5'
      '#multiple__sorting': false
      '#element':
        teilnehmer_name:
          '#type': textfield
          '#title': Name
        teilnehmer_alter:
          '#type': select
          '#options':
            18: ≥18
            17: 17
            16: 16
            15: 15
            14: 14
            13: 13
            12: 12
            11: 11
            10: 10
            9: 9
            8: 8
            7: 7
            6: 6
            5: 5
            4: 4
            3: 3
            2: 2
            1: 1
            0: 0
          '#title': Alter
```

Comment: You can always hide it with css !!

Comment: Yes, CSS is something I will consider – looking at the code, I will have to make both `#edit-fieldname-add-submit` and `.form-item-fieldname-add-more-items` invisible.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the 
"Minimum amount of items" and 
"Number of empty items" to the same number the add more won't appear.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Here is the YAML source for basic multiple text field

```
textfield:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': textfield
  '#multiple': 5
  '#multiple__min_items': '5'
  '#multiple__empty_items': '5'
```

Here is the YAML source for multiple custom composite

```
custom_composite:
  '#type': custom_composite
  '#title': custom_composite
  '#multiple': 5
  '#multiple__min_items': '5'
  '#multiple__empty_items': '5'
  '#multiple__sorting': false
  '#multiple__operations': false
  '#element':
    textfield:
      '#type': textfield
      '#title': textfield
    select:
      '#type': select
      '#options': days
      '#title': select
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for. I've tried your example, with various equal values for min_items and empty_items.

Comment: What version of the Webform module are you using? 

Please post an example of the generated YAML.

Comment: Sure. See edits above.

Comment: The key trick is '#multiple', '#multiple__min_items', and '#multiple__empty_items' all have to be same value.

Comment: '#multiple: 5' means there is a fixed number of five elements, therefore webform will not display the add more button, and not display the + and – buttons next to each row. But that's not what I'm looking for, as I need an arbitrary number of elements (unlimited).

Comment: Okay, that is not currently supported. You should use CSS. On mobile, the 'Add more' is needed because the add/remove buttons are hidden.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think, this issue is probably not specific to webforms, but to Drupal's Form API.